# ID this 90's animated children's film about alien invasion to forest

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon, alien-invasion

Probably an animated children film from the 90's.

Small aliens invade earth and land in the forest and evntually defeated by the animals I think or maybe some small other creatures. (the humans never knew they were invaded lol)

I remember the first secne with the aliens, they were flying above a soccer staduim or watch the game on the screen in the space ship and they were wondering why all these people are chasing this ball.... they thought it was very valuable.

(maybe they kidnaped and impersonated one of the animals)

TNX

Comment: Do you remember anything about the style of animation? Was in American? Japanese? Simple? Showed shading and depth? Was it cheap or well produced? Were the animals very anthropomorphic, or were they more realistic looking, did they talk?

Comment: Small soldiers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ***Katy and the Katerpillar Kids***!!! I'd also been looking for this for years, and I found the answer buried deep in another forum.

The scene opens with the aliens watching a screen where several scenes flash by and are discussed. One of which is a soccer game. They speculate as to why they are fighting over the ball, and decide the ball must be valuable. I've been searching for this same film, based on different criteria, as I didn't have a memory of the soccer scene at the beginning, but upon finding and watching the movie, I found it fits my memory, and the memory stated above.